# Is there a way of listing the row number of cells that have triggered a conditionally formatting rule in another sheet?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm looking for a way to list all the row numbers of cells that have triggered a conditionally formatting rule (that changes the cell colour red or yellow) into another worksheet. Is this possible?  I have a 180,000 rows and I'm having to zoom out to 10% then scrolling down to see the highlighted cells. It's properly time consuming

Not looking for the code, just looking for a nudge in the right direction.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

180,000 rows with conditional formatting, wow, that will take a while to refresh.

While you cannot create a formula based on the output of conditional formatting, you CAN create a formula that incorporates the same processing logic as conditional formatting. I would approach it like this:

- add a column to the sheet with the original data
- create a formula that uses the same input as the conditional formatting, but returns a text or a number instead of applying a color
- on a separate sheet, use the new Dynamic Array Filter() function to filter the data by the output of the new formula column.

Filter() is documented here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

If you run an older version of Excel that doesn't have Filter, you can sort the data table by the new column to help locate the rows that meet/don't meet the condition in the formula column.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, thanks for your input! I'll give it a go and report back

Comment: Re: 180,000 rows with conditional formatting, wow, that will take a while to refresh. - Thankfully I managed to get the CFO to invest in some high end number crunching gaming rigs so what used to take 2 hrs to complete take 15 min :) 
Thank you it worked very nicely!